# how to create a list in LISP and accepting elements of list from user?

Tags: list, lisp

how to create a list in LISP and accepting elements of list from user?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you have a list, say, (a b c) and want the user to select items from the list?

Comment: how is it that this question has got 3 upvotes? An upvote should be casted upon well written questions.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `read` function to read user input. For example:

```
[6]> (list (read) (read))
joe
moe
(JOE MOE)
```

`joe` and `moe` are my input lines, terminated by a newline (pressing Enter). The `list` function creates a new list.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read the elements of a list of unknown length, you could do it like this (takes input until NIL) [CL]:

```
(loop for read = (read)
      while read collect read)
```

Alternatively, the easiest possibility actually is:

```
(read)
```

Because the user may enter (foo bar baz 1 2 3) here, too.